# Is there any way to relay the data(stud.id) to the POST form?

Tags: python, html, django

```
{% for stud in student %}  
      <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{stud.id}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{stud.name}}</td>
        {% if x %}
        <td class="text-center">{{stud.main_sub}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{stud.fourth_sub}}</td>
        {% endif %}  
        <td class="text-center">
        <div>
        
          <a class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded " href="{% url 'updatestudent' stud.id %}"  style="width: 0.75in;">
            Edit
          </a>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" style="width: 0.75in;">
            Delete
          </button>
        
      </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %} 
    </tbody>
</table>    


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Confirmation</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Are you sure want to delete? {{stud.id}}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <form action="" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or maybe you could point me to some docs I could read. I'm new into programming and I'm learning based of off what my demo project needs.
In this code, I used django templating for loop to loop through all the objects and posted em in a table. table has an option to delete which leads to a popup confirmation. Problem is I couldn't find any way to relay the data from the for loop part to the popup part where the post form is.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.